# Mysterious functions

Tags: functions, computational-mathematics

I originally asked the following question in stackoverflow, but the question is closed because some members meant that the question is about math([see the following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197507/mysterious-functions))

So I will give a try here:

I´m currently reading the book **Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient**. The author wrote in page 4:

> "Curiously, there are functions that are known to exist, but nobody knows how to compute their values."

Could anyone give me an example of such a function?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. The best and only thing I can, however, do is to give you a link:
[Non-computable functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29197/non-computable-but-easily-described-arithmetical-functions)

Hopefully, this answers your question.